# Question Regarding solution of this Problem $ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty }f(x) + f'(x) =L $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I Know how to solve this Problem. The difficulty which I face is about the way in Which my Friend solved this Question

If  $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)+f'(x) = L$ Then prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)= L$

He done it by taking  $g(x)=e^{x} f(x).$

then  $Dg(x)=e^{x}f(x)+e^{x}Df(x)=e^{x} \left( f(x)+Df(x) \right).$

Then by $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{g(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{Dg(x)}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty} Df(x)+f(x)$

My Question is, Is there any analysis problem there, when we apply  l'Hospital's theorem.

Why they kept $e^x$ and then differentiated . I think we can make some wired things if it is allowed there  ...

Comment: How is one supposed to use L'Hopital to solve this question? Note that, by hypothesis, $$(L-\epsilon)e^x<g'(x)<(L+\epsilon)e^x$$ for every $x$ large enough, say $x>x_\epsilon$, hence $$g(x_\epsilon)-(L-\epsilon)e^{x_\epsilon}+(L-\epsilon)e^x<g(x)<g(x_\epsilon)-(L+\epsilon)e^{x_\epsilon}+(L+\epsilon)e^x$$ that is, $$A_\epsilon e^{-x}+L-\epsilon<f(x)<B_\epsilon e^{-x}+L+\epsilon$$ for some explicit $(A_\epsilon,B_\epsilon)$, for every $x>x_\epsilon$, from which one can conclude.

Comment: The proof by your friend is famous and also available on this website. Each step is valid. The idea of multiplication by $e^{x} $ is perhaps not so obvious but it comes from the integrating factor of the combination $f'+f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check that you are allowed to use L'Hopital's rule: you need to verify that indeed $\lim_{x\to+\infty}g(x) = +\infty$.

As to why they used $e^x$, I think the answer lies in the differentiation of $g$ itself: you can see for yourself that it's indeed a fairly nice trick.

Hint to another way to solve this: what would happen if $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)$ (provided it exists) were a number $R \not= L$ (or $\pm\infty$)? What could you say about the derivative?

Comment: if it was so then why cant we multiply numerator and denominator by $x$ when in finding limit of $\frac {sin(x)}{x} $ which on applying the rule leads to weird result

Comment: Well it depends: what limit do you mean? Does $x$ approach $0$, or $+\infty$ , or what else? If it's $0$, you can apply the rule, otherwise, you can't.